# Searching magnetic materials on the basis of point groups symmetry

Tags: condensed-matter

Where can I  search a list of magnetic materials by just knowing the point group symmetries?

Comment: By _magnetic materials_ do you mean ferromagnets?

Comment: I am Interested mainly on Antiferromagnets.